# examples of PHPunit tests

Tags: php, testing, laravel, phpunit, tdd

this is my first post, and i am looking for examples of phpunit tests which people use in regards to building a large laravel site.

So far, i have writen these, which test if the site is working, but am having difficultly in getting my head around the idea of testing the controllers of a laravel site.

this is my laravel tests so far, would really like to see what other people do to test their sites. Please paste any examples you have.

cheers

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EkVpWJud

Comment: Tests are very inidividual on each project, it depends on what you want to test. It can be tough to figure out what to test, that's why you should get a little more familiar with the subject in general. Seeing how other developers do it requires knowledge of the whole application topic and understanding of the business logic, I'm not sure if that would be very helpful. Have a look at some small scale examples and I also recommend this book by Jeffrey Way: https://leanpub.com/laravel-testing-decoded - And even if you're not sure: Any tests are still better than no tests at all ;)

Comment: Also, this queustion is very likely to get closed, because it doesn't really fit the Quastion & Answer style of StackOverflow. Your question as it is now can only be answered in a subjective and opinion based way, which should be avoided on StackOverflow. As already said, try to dive into the topic yourself and as soon as concrete questions occur on *how* to do something (and not *what* to do) you're very welcome to ask them here.

Comment: i have found some really useful tests in this repo https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site

Comment: Yep, that's a really good start! Pick some small laravel applications from github, figure out what they do and then look at the tests. But you should still keep in mind that everyone does it a little bit differently, in order to distinguish between good and bad practices you should be aware of what the main goal is.

Comment: thats why i asked on here, i like to learn from videos, repos and tutorials, just i dont really want the usual calculator examples. Its like the OOP tutroials that use cat/dog/animal as an example. I understand these examples, but i want a real world usable example. do you use laravel?

Comment: Yep, those examples mostly only try to introduce into PHPUnit and unit testing. But you're looking specifically for Laravel controller testing examples, which are not really unit tests. You should definitley check out https://laracasts.com/ - they have a bunch of excellent video tutorials on how to test, what to test and how to TDD, with a special focus on Laravel.

Comment: thanks, i will check them out when i get paid at the end of the month!